# How to convert String with â€œ (ISO-8859-1) characters to normal (UTF-8)characters?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

```
<li>Jain R.K. and Iyengar S.R.K., â€œAdvanced Engineering Mathematicsâ€, Narosa Publications,</li>
```

i have lot a raw html string in database. all the text have these weird characters. how can i convert to normal text for saving back it back in database.

```
$final = '<li>Jain R.K. and Iyengar S.R.K., â€œAdvanced Engineering Mathematicsâ€, Narosa Publications,</li>';
$final = utf8_encode($final);

$final = htmlspecialchars_decode($final);

$final = html_entity_decode($final, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$final = utf8_decode($final);

echo $final;
```

i tried above code, it displays correctly in web browser but still saving the same weird characters in database.

the charset of database is utf-8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$final = '<li>Jain R.K. and Iyengar S.R.K., â€œAdvanced Engineering Mathematicsâ€, Narosa Publications,</li>';

$final = str_replace("Â", "", $final);
$final = str_replace("â€™", "'", $final);
$final = str_replace("â€œ", '"', $final);
$final = str_replace('â€“', '-', $final);
$final = str_replace('â€', '"', $final);
```

for past datas, i replaced the weird characters with UTF-8 characters.

for future datas, i made the charset to utf8 in php, html and databases connections.

Answer (score 10):

`â€œ` is "Mojibake" for `“`.  You could try to avoid the non-ascii quotes, but that would only delay getting back into trouble.

You need to use `utf8mb4` in your tables and connections.  See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the likely causes of Mojibake.

Comment: I know a use case for avoiding the non-ASCII. Back when I was a MySQL+PHP developer, our website manager took our database backups with a third-party tool that didn't properly handle encoding. He once had to restore PROD from his backup only to find the characters were corrupted. I replaced all the Mojibake with HTML entities, and it immediately fixed our customer-facing embarrassment while requiring no new skills, no new processes, and very little risk. We needed that cowboy hack to buy us breathing room to do it right the next time.

Answer (score 3):

It safer to use **ftfy** tool to fix texts https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: SQL to fix 5 cases, plus comment on two un-fixable cases:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but I have encountered the same issue and fix it by fixing the charset in table for future input data.

I am using SQL Server 2017 and Collation is set to **`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`**

For existing characters I have written a script to pull the data from db and search each characters that match and fix those characters.

I have created two csv one contains the data with stray characters(email_templates.csv") and other contains clean html templates(clean_templates.csv).

To find the stray characters in your text/html you can use this online tool as well this is very helpful.

https://freetools.textmagic.com/unicode-detector

**UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart**

https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

**HTML codes and HTML special characters**

https://psdtowp.net/html-codes-special-characters.html

To verify the same in VS Code I have used extension **`Render Special Characters`** below is the link.

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miku3920.vscode-render-special-chars

PHP Script to verify and Fix the issue

```
$fileName = "email_templates.csv";
$ofileName = "clean_templates.csv";

try {

    $stray_chars = array(
        'â€”' => '-',
        'â€“' => '-',
        'â€˜'=> '\'',
        'â€™' => '\'',
        'â€œ' => '"' ,
        'â€' => '"',
        'Â'=>'',
        'Ã³'=> "ó",
        "Ã±" => "ñ",
        "Ã" => "í",
        "Ã¡"=> "á",
        "ï»¿" => '',
    );
    
    $contents = getEmailTemplateContent();

    $handle = fopen($fileName, "w") or die('Unable to open file');
    $ohandle = fopen($ofileName, "w") or die('Unable to open file');
    $data = [];
    $cleaned = [];
    $i = 0;

    $html = '';


    foreach($contents as $content) {

        $html = $content['html'];
        $clean = str_replace(array_keys($stray_chars), array_values($stray_chars), $html);

        $cleaned[$i] = $content['id']."-xxxx-".$clean;
        $data[$i] = $content['id']."-xxxx-".$html;
        //Fix stray characters in database
        updateEmailTemplateContent($clean, $content['id']);
        $i++;
    }

    fputcsv($handle, $data);
    fputcsv($ohandle, $cleaned);
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($ohandle);
}
catch(\PDOException $e) {
    $jobStatus = 'E';
    $jobError = $e->getMessage();
}
```