# How Do I convert list into str using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
type(df['Soft_skills'][0])
>>>str
```

I need to output like

```
df['Soft_skills'][0] = Management,Decision Making
```

and for second row

```
df['Soft_skills'][1] = None
```

I don't know how can I remove `"` and covert it into `str`format.

```
>>> df['Soft_skills']
0                       ["Management", "Decision Making"]
1                                                      []
2                                          ["Management"]
3                                                      []
4       ["Governance", "Management", "Leadership", "Te...
                              ...
1229                                                   []
1230                                                   []
1231                                                   []
1232                   ["Agenda (Meeting)", "Governance"]
1233                                                   []
Name: Soft_skills, Length: 1234, dtype: object
```

In some cases data is
`The syllabus for this course will cover the following:, \n, *,  The nature and purpose of cost and management accounting, \n, *,  Source documents and coding, \n, *,  Cost classification and measuring, \n, *,  Recording costs, \n, *,  Spreadsheets`
I replace this by using

```
d = {
'Not Mentioned':'',
"\r\n": "\n",
"\r": "\n",
'\u00a0':' ',
': \n, *,  ':'\n * ',
' \n,':'\n',
}
df=df.replace(d.keys(),d.values(),regex=True)
```

but nothing replaces what is the problem when I'm trying is there anything I missing?
I used also this

```
df['Course_content'] = df['Course_content']\
    .str.replace('Not Mentioned','')\
    .str.replace("\r\n", "\n")\
    .str.replace("\r", "\n")\
    .str.replace('\u00a0',' ')\
    .str.replace(', \n, *,  ','\n * ')\
    .str.replace(' \n,','\n')
```

but it also not working for me

Comment: can you run `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` and paste the output in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `strip()` and `replace()`:

```
df['Soft_skills']=(df['Soft_skills'].str.strip("[]")
              .str.replace("'",'')
              .replace('',float('nan'),regex=True))
```

### update:

firstly created a dictionary:

```
d={
    'Â':'',
    'â€™':"'",
    'â€œ':'"',
    'â€“':'-',
    'â€':'"'
}
```

Finally use `replace()` method:

```
df=df.replace(d.keys(),d.values(),regex=True)
```

**Source:** I created the dictionary from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48047198/14289892) as that was is for php but with same encoding problem

Comment: Is there a reason to use this vs. `df['Soft_skills'].apply(','.join)`? Seems unnecessarily complicated, but maybe there are performance reasons.

Comment: yup due to performance reason I didn't use `apply()`...btw added both solutions

Comment: first one is not working for me it joining all words like 
```
[,",M,a,n,a,g,e,m,e,n,t,",,, ,",D,e,c,i,s,i,o,...
1                                                     [,]
2                             [,",M,a,n,a,g,e,m,e,n,t,",]
3                                                     [,]
```

Comment: it was because column `'Soft_skills'` is of type string so use 2nd method...updated answer kindly have a look.... **:)**

Comment: `5â€“8 hours per week` that type some character in my csv file how can encoding or any other would be easy for me?

Comment: what is the easy way to clean and replace that typo characters?

Comment: yes you can replace them with their actual values...Updated answer kindlly have a look **:)**

Comment: I use `df.to_csv('sample.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)` I encode and it working for me but can you look at the updated question when I'm trying to replace but it not working for `\n`,`\r\n`.

Comment: `df['Course_content'] = df['Course_content']\
    .str.replace('Not Mentioned','')\
    .str.replace("\r\n", "\n")\
    .str.replace("\r", "\n")\
    .str.replace('\u00a0',' ')\
    .str.replace(', \n, *,  ','\n * ')\
    .str.replace(' \n,','\n')`
I'd have to replace this character and it's not working for me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232887/discussion-between-viren-ramani-and-anurag-dabas).